# error while running rake db:populate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

after running rake db:reset 
i rund rake db:populate and i'm getting this error don't know where it's coming from

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `+' for 4..5:Range

Tasks: TOP => db:populate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**in my task folder**

```
namespace :db do
  desc " Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
     admin = User.create!(name: "Emple User", 
                          email: "exampel@railstuttorial.org",    
                          password: "password",
                          password_confirmation: "password")
  admin.toggle!(:admin)                 
     99.times do |n|
        name = Faker::Name.name
        email = "example-#{n + 1}@railstutorial.org"
        password = "password"
        User.create!(name: name, email: email, password: password,     
                     password_confirmation: password)
     end   
     users = User.all(limit: 6)
     50.times do
       content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(4..5)
       users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
       content = nil 
     end             
  end


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a range to `Faker::Lorem.sentence` in your `50.times` loop.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but that method is expecting an integer (did you mean 4 or 5?) and when it tries to add something to it within the `Faker::Lorem` code it is causing that error.

Comment: When i pass 5 or 4  i get ``Range unspecified. Specify the :in, :within, :maximum, :minimum, or :is option.``

Comment: I think it might be a different line causing that error. That error comes from an incorrect use of `validates_length_of` possibly on the class that is the on the other end of the association `microposts` from user.

Comment: so do you mean i need to get rid of validates length

Comment: No, I mean that the way you're using it might be invalid. You could try it without or you could try fixing it. Or ask another question about it I guess :)